# Error installing Postgres module in Node.js and 2 other node.js questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knockout.js, express

I am having trouble installing the Postgres database module for Node.js, every time I run the command "npm install pg" I get the following error:

```bash
C:\>npm install pg<br>
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg<br>
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg<br>
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg/-/pg-0.12.1.tgz<br>
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg/-/pg-0.12.1.tgz<br>
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.2<br>
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.2<br>
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/-/generic-pool-2.0.2.tgz<br>
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/-/generic-pool-2.0.2.tgz<br>

> pg@0.12.1 install C:\node_modules\pg<br>
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)<br>


C:\node_modules\pg>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-b<br>
in\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild<br>
'pg_config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,<br>
operable program or batch file.<br>
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 1. while trying to load b<br>
inding.gyp<br>
gyp ERR! configure error<br>
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1<br>
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module<br>
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:420:16)<br>
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)<br>
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)<br>
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600<br>
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu<br>
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"<br>
gyp ERR! cwd C:\node_modules\pg<br>
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.17<br>
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.8.2<br>
gyp ERR! not ok<br>
pg@0.12.1 node_modules\pg<br>
└── generic-pool@2.0.2<br>
```

This error occurs on both my work machine (linux/windows box) and my personal machine (windows) at home. Any ideas?

Also I should mention I already have Python 2.7.3 installed.

Comment: Do you have the PostgreSQL libraries and headers installed? Your problem with `pg_config --libdir` suggest that you don't or you have a PATH problem (i.e. `pg_config` is not in your PATH).

Comment: I have removed some secondary questions that were appended to this one. Please post new questions for them. The questions were:

*1) I've heard that there are two different ways to connect to the database using Node.js, one way is via javascript using the pg module and the other is via a native extension (can't remember the name). What do you guys recommend me to use and which is easier/better for a novice in Node.js to pick up?*

Comment: *2) I've read people write about developing in either Node.js only, or via Node.js/Express combo or Node.js/Knockout library. Is one better than the other? This is in terms of the web application able to access a remote database (as per our project).*

Answer (score 5):

You're on Windows:

```
'pg_config' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

so I suggest you get a pre-built binary of the pg module. Compiling things on windows is ... fun.

The immediate error is that the `pg_config` executable is not on the `PATH`, but there'll be lots more after you fix that. Get a prebuilt executable unless you plan on a journey of discovery and swearing.

Comment: well you happen to know where I could get a pre-built pg binary? Otherwise I'll have to work with linux entirely. I did actually add pg_config to my windows environment path and it was complaining about make not being installed due to there being no vc++ 2008 etc...

Comment: Okay I have pg_config installed to /usr/bin/ folder. It was already there on our SuSE Enterprise Linux box. Now if I type in pg_config in the terminal it runs just fine...I already have the path of it in $PATH so what could be wrong?

Comment: @JackSparrow123 Er ... aren't you on Windows? You didn't specify in the question, but the error message `is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` is Windows-specific. Now you're talking about SuSE and `/usr/bin`. What's going on? If you've copied `pg_config` over from a SuSE box to Windows, that really won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Specify Postgres bin folder in PATH variable, then don't forget to restart cmd.exe with Administrator rights

Answer (score 1):

Install postgres db (https://www.postgresql.org/download/) and make sure its bin folder path present in environment variable

[image]